# Как указать, чтобы можно было открыть файл своим приложением?

Tags: java, android, intent-filter

Мое приложение открывает текстовые файлы.

Чтобы оно предлагалось при выборе "чем открыть файл", я внес изменения в манифест, здесь все ок.

Но, как передать адрес файла приложению не могу разобраться.

**Сделал [вот так](http://dogma7.com/blog/722)  и получил, что хотел**

Answer (score 0):

Sending simple data to other apps
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

**UPD:**
Как принять данные:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String filePath = b.getString("filePath");
if(filePath != null) {
    //ваш код
}
```

Как отправить данные:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Chose app:"));
```

Comment: Ну и зачем мне эти ссылки на документацию как переслать данные из моего приложения и вызвать какой-то  intent?. Я просил помочь написать правильно синтаксис, а не посылать меня изучать принцип действия. Я понимаю в общих чертах, но не могу написать именно правильно. Твоя ссылка это не о том. Мне надо просто сделать так чтобы пользователь мог открыть файл моим приложением. Пользователь выбирает файл, ему предлагается мое приложение , он его выбирает оно запускается(это работает) а дальше надо как-то сообщить моему приложению адрес файла

Comment: 1. у меня возникал такой же вопрос как у тебя, и документация по ссылке мне полностью помогла в решении моего вопроса. 2. Суть же такая: если ты хочешь вызвать свое приложение то тебе в интент нужно передать данные (в твоем случае ссылку на файл), а уже у себя с помощью бандла получить эту ссылку. 3. попытался помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно. Но...Ну так дай код рабочий, если ты знаешь как)).  Мне не нужна суть. Суть я пойму по рабочему куску кода и дальше смогу разбираться с аналогичными задачами. Я не очень хорошо владею синтаксисом и часто недопонимаю, что именно  я мог бы поменять под себя. Лично я когда отвечаю людям по вопросам разработки в тех областях, где я специалист - то даю просто готовое решение чтобы они могли скопировать вставит и разобраться.

Comment: обновил, посмотри

Comment: ладно. перефразирую. у меня есть всего лишь одна основная Activity в которой есть

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

}
Куда мне надо написать какой фрагмент кода определяющий что приложение было вызвано для открытия файла и получить имя этого файла ?

Comment: переменная savedInstanceState как бэ намекает что в ней хранится Bundle с этой переменной и работайте в onCreate

Comment: отличный ответ. чтоб тебя врач так объяснял способ приема препарата, а ты не знал это водой запивать и в жопу засовывать. и он тебе такой "ну форма кагбэ намекает". еще раз повторю: в какое место написать код при том, что вызов его НАВЕРНОЕ в onCreate(. а может и не в в нем, тогда где?   В какое место надо засунуть препарат?! Куда и менно и в каком виде надо написать этот код чтобы он сработал? Эти 2 строчки кода я видел в разных вариантах 10 раз. Целиком рабочий код как должен выглядеть?